# Как получить доступ к измененому свойству класса внутри класса?

Tags: php

```
class Test extends Common {
  public function index() {
    echo $this->name; // выводит 1 ... как здесь получить 2 ?
  }
}

class Common {
  public $name = 1;
  public function run() {
    $this->name = 2;
    $test = new Test();
    $test->index();
  }
}

$app = new Common();
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас в коде та-а-акое намешано... Очень советую почитать про ООП и наследование в PHP.

```php
<?php
class Test extends Common {
  public function index() {
    parent::run();
    echo $this->name;
  }
}

class Common {
  public $name = 1;
  public function run() {
    $this->name = 2;
  }
}

$app = new Test();
$app->index();
```